# Can't receive snmpv3 trap with adventnet

Tags: java, snmp

I followed [this page](http://yr512656630.iteye.com/blog/1608162) to create a TrapListener, and my code looks like this:

```
public class SnmpTrapd implements TrapListener {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        // instantiate SNMP Trap Receiver bean  
        SnmpTrapReceiver trapreceiver = new SnmpTrapReceiver();  
        // set the port in which the trap is received  
        trapreceiver.setPort(162);  
        // register the listener for trap events  
        trapreceiver.setAutoInformResponse(true);   
        trapreceiver.setLocalAddresses(new String[]{new String("192.168.1.2")});
        trapreceiver.addTrapListener(new SnmpTrapd());  
        trapreceiver.setTrapAuthEnable(false);
        System.out.println("Waiting to receive traps .......");  

    }  

    @Override  
    public void receivedTrap(TrapEvent trap) {  
        System.out.println("Got a trap from: " + trap.getRemoteHost());  
        // print PDU details  
        System.out.println(((SnmpTrapReceiver) trap.getSource()).getMibOperations().toString(trap.getTrapPDU()));  
        if (trap.getTrapPDU().getCommand() == SnmpAPI.TRP_REQ_MSG) {  
            com.adventnet.snmp.mibs.MibTrap trapDefn = trap.getTrapDefinition();  
            if (trapDefn != null) // print name and description  
                System.out.println("Trap Name: " + trapDefn.getName() + "\nDescr: " + trapDefn.getDescription());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

However, it didn't receive anything when I create a snmp v3 trap with my Fortigate 60D. I'm sure the trap is sent from the fortigate since I've monitored the interface on my computer with wireshark.

What's more,I can receive the v3 trap when I use another api (rather than adventnet), so I'm pretty sure the setting of fortigate is correct.
Is there any problem with my code?

---

### Update

I also tried what [this page](https://www.webnms.com/snmp/help/snmpapi/snmpv3/tutorials/traps/hlapi_snmpreceivetrap.html) said, but still in vain.
(Though I'm wondering the page is talk about v2c trap instead of v3...)

Answer (score 0):

You set `setTrapAuthEnable` to false which means you would like to drop some v3 TRAP messages. Is that what you expected? Read the documentation and also check the packets sent by 60D, then you will see if that's the cause.

Comment: I've set setTrapAuthEnable to true but still the same. Should I config other settings?

Answer (score 0):

Trap receiver working example.

```
public class TestTrapV3_2 implements CommandResponder {

    private static final String _V3_USERNAME = "newUser";
    private static final String _V3_AUTHENTICATION_PASSPHRASE = "abc12345";

    private static final String _V3_PRIVACY_PASSPHRASE = "abc12345";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        TestTrapV3_2 trap = new TestTrapV3_2();
        trap.startTrapReceiver();
    }

    private synchronized void startTrapReceiver() throws IOException {
        ThreadPool threadPool = ThreadPool.create("DispatcherPool", 10);

        Address listenAddress = new UdpAddress("localhost/162");
        TransportMapping transport = null;
        if (listenAddress instanceof UdpAddress) {
            transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping(
                    (UdpAddress) listenAddress);
        } else {
           /* transport = new DefaultTcpTransportMapping(
                    (TcpAddress) listenAddress);*/
        }
        USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance(), new OctetString(
                MPv3.createLocalEngineID()), 0);
        usm.setEngineDiscoveryEnabled(true);

        MessageDispatcher mDispathcher = new MultiThreadedMessageDispatcher(
                threadPool, new MessageDispatcherImpl());

        // add message processing models
        mDispathcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv1());
        mDispathcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv2c());
        mDispathcher.addMessageProcessingModel(new MPv3(usm));
        // add all security protocols
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols();
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new PrivAES128());

        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);

        CommunityTarget target = new CommunityTarget();

        target.setCommunity(new OctetString("public"));

        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(mDispathcher, transport);

        UsmUser usmUser = new UsmUser(new OctetString("newUser"),
                   AuthSHA.ID,
                   new OctetString(_V3_AUTHENTICATION_PASSPHRASE),
                   PrivAES128.ID,
                   new OctetString(_V3_PRIVACY_PASSPHRASE)
           );
        snmp.getUSM().addUser(new OctetString(_V3_USERNAME),usmUser);
        snmp.addCommandResponder(this);

        transport.listen();
        System.out.println("listening");
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processPdu(CommandResponderEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Received PDU...");
        PDU pdu = arg0.getPDU();

        if (pdu != null) {
            System.out.println("Security level = "+ arg0.getSecurityLevel() );
            System.out.println("Peer Address = "+ arg0.getPeerAddress() );
            System.out.println("Trap Type = " + pdu.getType());
            System.out.println("Variables = " + pdu.getVariableBindings());
            System.out.println("**************************");
        }
    }
}
```